# How do I access specific blocks of an image in MATLAB? (Not crop)

Tags: matlab

For a university assignment I am tasked with applying an effect to three separate areas of an image that is 512x512 in size. As shown by the following image

[image]

However I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about accessing those specific regions of the image. I can't use crop, as I'm required to further transform and rebuild the image later on so I can verify that the effects have been applied correctly. However short of doing:

```
imageSize = size(I,1);
imageSizeHalf = imageSize/2;
imageSizeQuarter = imageSize/4;
imageSizeEighth = imageSize/8;
```

And then trying to access the matrix dimensions that way (which I'm not even sure how to do, what would I need to do to achieve this?) I'm not sure how I'm supposed to access those three specific regions of the image.

Comment: You can use `I(row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end)` to access a section of the image (assuming single channel). Where `row_start`, `row_end`, `col_start`, and `col_end` are variables you would define containing the start and end rows/columns that you want to access. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I feel like this is quite a hacky way of accessing the areas I need, but it works nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: What makes you feel that this is hacky?

Comment: @jodag Just one quick question sorry, if I place a value 0 in this, like in the line `w1_region = [I(imageSizeQuarter:imageSizeHalf, 0:imageSizeQuarter)];` I get the error `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` How do I start the column beginning at 0?

Comment: Matrices and arrays in MATLAB use 1 based indexing. I.e. use `1:imageSizeQuarter` to access columns 1 through 128. You also probably want `I(imageSizeQuarter+1:imageSizeHalf, 1:imageSizeQuarter)` because of the indexing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this a bit neater would be to define a function which returns the indices of the rows and columns for a particular block.

```
function [rows, cols] = get_block_indices(block_row, block_col, block_size)
    rows = (1:block_size) + block_size*(block_row-1);
    cols = (1:block_size) + block_size*(block_col-1);
```

Then you can, for example, access the block W1 which is on row 1, column 2 of the block grid as follows

```
[rows, cols] = get_block_indices(1, 2, block_size);
I(rows, cols) = your_effect_function(I(rows, cols));
```

assuming `block_size = size(I,1)/4`.